# Traduzione di "Homomorphic Hiding"

Tags: translation, mathematics

Sto conducendo una ricerca sulla crittografia omomorfa e mi sono imbattuto nei cosiddetti "[Homomorphic Hidings](https://blog.z.cash/snark-explain/)". C'è qualcuno qui che mangia insalate di matematica che possa darmi una mano a tradurre il nome di questa funzione?

Avevo pensato a "Nascondiglio Omomorfo" ma suona veramente male.

Forse considerato che si tratta una sorta di hash potrebbe essere accettabile chiamarlo in italiano semplicemente "Hash Omomorfo"?

Comment: Potrebbe andare _offuscamento omomorfico_?

Comment: “Occultamento omomorfo”?

Comment: Terrò queste opzioni in considerazione. Grazie!

Comment: Direi che normalmente in contesti tecnici e matematici è consuetudine tenere gli originali inglesi se non è immediato trovare un vocabolo corrispondente in italiano (considera che, per chi legge, potrebbe non essere immediato capire se un "offuscamento" e un "hiding" letto in un altro articolo sono la stessa cosa o no). Quindi in questo caso io direi "hiding omomorfo", oppure, come dici tu, "hash omomorfo", visto che anche a me sembra sostanzialmente la stessa cosa.

Comment: Omomorfismo nascosto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alla fine, dopo essermi consultato con un mio Prof. che mi fa da supervisore, siamo giunti alla conclusione che alcuni termini tecnici (tra i quali anche questo in oggetto della discussione) si possono lasciare in lingua inglese, l'importante è far comprendere a chi legge il loro funzionamento.
Grazie comunque per le risposte!

Comment: Il resto del libro (o tesi o articolo) è in italiano? Se sì, non vedo perché singole parole debbano essere in italiano... Mi rattrista un po' che rinunciamo già in partenza a continuare ad avere un lessico scientifico italiano.

Comment: Il resto sì, ad ogni modo ho cercato di tradurre quanto possibile (una parte della mia tesi copre un argomento le cui documentazioni esistono solo in lingua inglese).

Answer (score 3):

Io suggerirei come traduzione “*offuscamento  omomorfo*”, dato che in informatica i cosiddetti “obfuscators” vengono utilizzati per rendere difficoltosa la decompilazione del codice.